# Berry Esseen type bound for two-sample problem

Tags: probability

This question is about rate of convergence of CLTs. Let $(X_{i})_{1}^{n}$ be i.i.d with absolute third moment $\beta_{X}$. Let $(Y_{i})_{1}^{m}$ be i.i.d with absolute third moment $\beta_{Y}$. Both $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ have unit variance and mean equal to some constant $c$.

The CLT gives that:

$T_{m,n}=\frac{\bar{X} - \bar{Y}}{\sqrt{1/n +1/m}}$ converges in distribution to a normal as $m$ and $n$ tend to infinity (i.e. assuming the lindeberg condition holds for the sequence $T_{k}$ for $(m,n)=(m_{k}, n_{k})$). What can be said about the rate of convergence in terms of $m$ and $n$?

In a one sample problem the convergence occurs at rate $1/\sqrt{n}$.